# Radio button unable to set initial value

Tags: python, tkinter

The following code gets invoked with a click of a button :

```
def delivery():
    
    deliveryWin = tk.Toplevel( root )
    deliveryWin.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (200, 100, 0, 0))
    
    
    Grid.columnconfigure(deliveryWin, index=0, weight=1)
    Grid.columnconfigure(deliveryWin, index=1, weight=1)
   
    
    Grid.rowconfigure(deliveryWin, 0, weight=1)
    Grid.rowconfigure(deliveryWin, 1, weight=1)
    
   
    ExpVar = IntVar()
    ExpR1 = Radiobutton(deliveryWin, text="Excellent", variable=ExpVar, value=1)
    ExpR1.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=5, pady=1, sticky='w')
    ExpR2 = Radiobutton(deliveryWin, text="Very Good", variable=ExpVar, value=2)
    ExpR2.grid(column=1, row=0, padx=5, pady=1, sticky='w')
   
    ExpVar.set(1)
```

I expect the first radio button to be selected but both remain unselected as windows open.
Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Is there a specific reason for setting the value after the definition of the RadioButtons? Could you not do `ExpVar = IntVar(value=1)` on init?

Comment: Tried setting value before definition of radio buttons, still it doesn't work

Comment: Your `IntVar` is being garbage-collected as soon as the function returns, since there are no remaining references to it.  That leaves your Radiobuttons with no place to store their state.  `global ExpVar` would be the simplest fix - you're going to somehow have to extend its lifetime anyway, if you ever hope to read the state of the buttons.

Comment: making ExpVar global fix the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have an issue with the scope of your variables.
But usually you have 3 possibilities to set up the variable :

```
# first possibility
ExpVar = IntVar(value=1)

# second possibility
ExpVar = IntVar(None, 1)

# third possibility
ExpVar = IntVar()
ExpVar.set(1)
```